# Prestashop problem with renderList: When I try to edit a row, only one field is getting the value, not the others

Tags: input, module, prestashop, helper

I'm creating a prestashop module for my company.
I'm using helpers to do a clean job.
The problem is with my renderForm ! When I try to edit a row, only the id_product field is getting the value, not the 3 others..
So I'd like to understand why ?

```
/* Constructeur */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->bootstrap = true;
    /* Pour aller chercher la table correspondante dans la base */
    $this->table = 'reverdy_aliments';
    $this->className = 'ReverdyPrices';
    $this->deleted = false;

    $this->context = Context::getContext();
    /* Pour ajouter la checkbox à gauche */
    /*$this->bulk_actions = array(
        'delete' => array(
            'text' => $this->l('Delete selected'),
            'confirm' => $this->l('Delete selected items?'),
            'icon' => 'icon-trash'
        )
    );*/

    /* Pour préciser que la clé primaire n'est pas 'id_'.$table */
    $this->identifier = 'id_product';

    parent::__construct();
}

/* Pour ajouter les boutons */
public function renderList()
{
    /* Boutons sur les lignes du tableau */
    $this->addRowAction('edit');

    /* Champs voulus dans le tableau */
    $this->fields_list = array(
        'id_product' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Produit'),
            'align' => 'center',
            'callback' => 'getAlimentNameById'
        ),
        'departement' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Département'),
            'align' => 'center'
        ),
        'quantite_kg' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Quantité'),
            'align' => 'center'
        ),
        'prix_ht' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Prix H.T.'),
            'align' => 'center'
        )
    );

    return parent::renderList();
}

/* Pour récupérer directement le nom des produits */
public function getAlimentNameById($echo,$row)
{
    $id_product = (int)$row['id_product'];
    if($id_product){
        $produit = new Product($id_product);
        return $produit->name[$this->context->language->id];
    }
    return "";
}

/* Pour le formulaire de modification */
public function renderForm()
{
    if (!($obj = $this->loadObject(true)))
        return;

    $this->fields_form = array(
        'tinymce'=> false,
        'legend' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Produit'),
            'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
        ),
        'input' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'id_product',
                'label' =>  $this->l('Produit'),
                'disabled' => true
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'departement',
                'label' =>  $this->l('Département'),
                'disabled' => true
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'quantite_kg',
                'label' =>  $this->l('Quantité en kg'),
                'disabled' => true
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'prix_ht',
                'label' =>  $this->l('Prix H.T.')
            )
        ),
        'submit' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            'name' => 'submitAdd'.$this->table
        )
    );

    /*$this->fields_value = array('departement' => 'test');
    $this->fields_value['id_employee_default'] = $default_employee;*/

    return parent::renderForm();
}
```

Comment: You have shared not a full code (what `class` it `extends`?) And from your description it is not clear what are you looking for: `renderList` or `renderForm`. Anyhow, you need to pass your variables to `$this->fields_list = array(...)` or `$this->fields_value = array(...)`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer !
My class is : `class AdminReverdyPricesController extends ModuleAdminController`
And I'm looking for why when I'm clicking on edit on a field from the fields_list, I have no values in the inputs..

Comment: I have to say, I already saw `$this->fields_value = array(...)` but it's just if I want a default value no? For this case, I just want to get the values from the row I'm editing..

Is that clear enough ? Sorry for my english..

Answer (score 0):

We have seen with Benoit that the problem was about the ObjectModel "ReverdyPrices" wich one was not included into the module with a include or a require_once.